# AWS Lambda + Kinesis : from what position in the stream do lambda functions restart?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I wonder what happens when new code is uploaded to a lambda function.
Does it restart from the selected starting point at the function creation (i.e: Trim Horizon) ?

Answer (score 2):

The stream will continue processing from the last record processed on each shard of the stream.  Internally, it is basically running the KCL and forwarding Kinesis Records to the lambda infrastructure.  The KCL snapshot will be used to restart the function at the last position.

We verified this on my team using a simple function to insert incrementing numbers into a multi-shard kinesis stream, and then deploying code multiple times while a lambda function echoed the stream contents into CloudWatch logs.

Comment: is there a way to force it to restart from the trim horizon?